# Looks like terminology

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice

What does "looks like" imply?

Are two things that are identical "look like" each other, or do they "look exactly like" each other.

Definition of looks like - bear a physical resemblance to

Why do people say:

A: "This dog looks like my dog."
B: "That's because it IS your dog!"

If something is one's dog, then how come people say Person A's dog looks like Person A's dog?

Comment: Doesn't Person A's dog look like Person A's dog? That dog is a member of a special group of dogs that look like Person A's dog - but not all dogs that look like Person A's actually ARE person A's.

Comment: Because _looks like_ is an estimation, and everybody handles on-the-fly estimates differently. Phrases like these don't have exact definitions. Some people think it's visual only, and others think it's identificational. Everything looks like itself, at least to most people, most of the time. But one can make a mistake because one thing looks like another.

Comment: Would Person A's opinion on what the dog looks like be true or be false?

Comment: Like John Lawler said, "looks like" does not have an exact meaning - especially because it is subjective, as are all statements that involve a sense.  We can't say whether the following is true or false: tuna fish tastes like chicken.  What we can say about "looks like" is that we normally do not say that a thing looks like itself.  Usually such a comparison requires a special context: *I don't look like myself **today***

Comment: This looks like a rant.

Comment: It's not a rant, but a genuine question.

Comment: But it *looks like* a rant.

Answer (score 0):

*Looks exactly like* is a narrower concept than *looks like*, so, if **x** looks exactly like **y**, it follows, as a matter of logic, that **x** looks like **y**.

If 'two things . . . are identical', that is, if they are not really two distinct things but one and the same thing, can we say that 'they' look like each other? More simply put, can we say '**x** looks like **x**'? This is where the distinction between syntax and semantics, on one side, and pragmatics, on the other, becomes relevant. So far as the syntax and semantics are concerned, we can always say '**x** looks like **x**'; that is necessarily true, no matter what **x** is. However, as a matter of pragmatics, there is practically never an occasion to say it; the concept of looking like is useful only when we are comparing distinct things. One's saying '**x** looks like **x**', although true, is thus bound to produce puzzled looks everywhere except in a philosophy classroom.